# Webpack configuration to allow import

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am creating a basic structure where the controller.js would need some Views to be imported from view.js and hence this is what I am using in the controller.js

`import View from './View'`

However there was an issue with the bundler with webpack and I ended up visiting this page

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/

and below is webpack.config.js.. I've added the lines at the end to the RULES as metioned in the documentation

I ran npm install `npm install imports-loader --save-dev`

```
// SOURCE OF TUTORIAL
// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpGLUVbqoYQ&t=1205s

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: false,
  entry: {
    main: "./src/js/controller.js",
    model: "./src/js/model.js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/main.html",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader", // injects STYLES into DOM
          "css-loader", // turns CSS into commonjs
          "sass-loader", // turns SASS into CSS
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ["html-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|gif|svg|jpe?g)$/,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: require.resolve("./path/to/example.js"),
        loader: "imports-loader",
        options: {
          type: "module",
          imports: "default lib myName",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

The last section of the rule is what I have added.. it's a basic copy paste without really understanding what it does and it didn't work.. I am obviously doing somethibg wrong but I could not figure it out even after reading the section at the link above..

Could someone explain how the last section should be configured so that I am able to use import? I've recently created this webpack configuration based on a youtube tutorial so my knowledge on webpack is very basic..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how the `import-loader` works. Usually, most people just use `babel-loader` with `preset-env` and be done with it. It is explained [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/). However, in general, a loader will only work for files that match your `test` condition, which you set to a singular file at `./path/to/example.js`. You probably want to remove `test`, or replace it with the name of your `src` folder. Also consider its documentation [here](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/) and google for relevant examples.

Comment: thanks @Domi ..:-).. you are right.. I was complicating my life with import-loader and I guess babel-loader is what everyone uses for this. so I've installed that and am trying to things with that.. it's not the easier package to mess with .. this webpack..;-).. anyway thanks again for your advise..